# pytest passing data for cleanup

Tags: python, pytest, web-api-testing

I'm writing tests for a post api, which returns the resource that gets created. But how do I pass this data to a fixture in python so it can cleanup after the test is completed

Cleanup:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def delete_after_post(request):
    def cleanup():
        // Get ID of resource to cleanup
        // Call Delete api with ID to delete the resource
    request.addfinalizer(cleanup)
```

Test:

```
 def test_post(delete_after_post):
     Id = post(api)
     assert Id
```

What is the best way to pass the response(ID) back to to the fixture for the cleanup to kick in. Don't want to do the cleanup as part of the test.

Comment: Why not use per-method setup/teardown? Save ID in the setup and cleanup in the teardown.

Comment: ID is something generated by the API under test and is not known in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access that ID using request instance and use anywhere in your code by `request.instance.variableName`. Like, Suppose your method for deleting id `delete(resource_id)`, here

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def delete_after_post(request):
    def cleanup():
        print request.node.resourceId
        # Get ID of resource using request.instance.resourceId
        # Call Delete api with ID to delete the resource

    request.addfinalizer(cleanup)
```

**test file xyz_test.py**

```
def test_post(delete_after_post,request):
    request.node.resourceId='3'
```

Comment: so request holds the context for the test run. This sounds a decent way of getting the task done.

Comment: Nope. Looks like it doesnt seem to recognise "request" in the test

`>       request.instance.resourceId = 3
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resourceId'`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Which works completely fine at my end.

Comment: No. The fixture or the test is not part of any class. The fixture is in a file called conftest.py and the test is in a file test_post.py and they both are under a package (folder) test

Comment: Can't you bind your test method only into a class?? Bcz scope of fixture and test both needs to be same here to use request instance.

Comment: No these are purely functional scripts and cant be created as classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147625/discussion-between-user3434013-and-chanda-korat).

Comment: how will i run it on the test case

Answer (score 1):

I created a fixture that collects cleanup functions for this purpose:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def cleaner():
    funcs = []
    def add_func(func):
        funcs.append(func)
    yield add_func
    for func in funcs:
        func()

def test_func(cleaner):
    x = 5
    cleaner(lambda: print('cleaning', x))
```

This way you don't need a separate fixture for each use case.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did was create a class called TestRunContext and set static variables to pass around data.

File: test_run_context.py

```
class TestRunContext:
      id_under_test = 0
```

File: conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def delete_after_post():
    print('hello')

    yield

    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/centres/{0}'.format(TestRunContext.id_under_test)
    resp = requests.delete(url)
```

File: test_post.py

`def test_creates_post(delete_after_post):
    post_data ={
        'name' : 'test',
        'address1': 'test',
        'city': 'test',
        'postcode': 'test',
    }
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/centres'
    data = requests.post(url, post_data)
    TestRunContext.id_under_test = data.id
    assert data`

This works for me for now. But hoping to find a better solution than using ContextManager file. Really dont like this solution.

Comment: This is not the best answer. The above answer by Chanda Korat is the better one so far.